# Flask/jinja2/JavaScript/HTML/Bootstrap TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I am using a bootstrap button class and when the button is clicked I send this.id to the javascript function caretToggle(). Because I have multiple bootstrap buttons I want to toggle the caret on I tried the method shown below but I received this error:

**Edit:**

I am also using flask and link the JavaSript file with jinja2 syntax like this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/caretToggle.js') }}"></script>
```

When I comment the way I link the file out and just put the javascript in script tags in the body of the html the code works as expected.

The curious part is the code all work as expected until I added a second button.

My preference is to keep all the javascript in a file can anyone help me solve this?

**End edit**

Error:

```
caretToggle.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

CDNS:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/darkly/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-nNK9n28pDUDDgIiIqZ/MiyO3F4/9vsMtReZK39klb/MtkZI3/LtjSjlmyVPS3KdN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

HTML snippet:

```
<div id="caretToggleMh">
    <button 
      id="mH" 
      class="btn btn-block btn-primary m-2 dropdown-toggle" 
      type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="#major-holders" 
      aria-expanded="false" 
      aria-controls="collapseExample" 
      onmousedown="caretToggle(this.id)">
      Major Holders
    </button>
</div>
<div id="caretToggleIh">
  <button 
    id="iH" 
    class="btn btn-block btn-primary m-2 dropdown-toggle"
    type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#collapseExample" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-controls="collapseExample"  
    onmousedown="caretToggle(this.id)">
   Institutional Holders
  </button>
</div>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
function caretToggle(clicked_id) {
    if (clicked_id == "mH") {
        console.log(clicked_id);
        var caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggleMh");
        caretElement.classList.toggle("dropup");
        console.log("class attribute contains: ", caretElement.className);
    } else if (clicked_id == "iH") {
        console.log(clicked_id);
        var caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggleiH");
        caretElement.classList.toggle("dropup");
        console.log("class attribute contains: ", caretElement.className);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's undefined, it doesn't exist, maybe try what dwosk said or there might be no classes (I don't understand how this classList works but maybe it's toggleing nothing)

Comment: If it's not solved your problem can you create a [codepen](https://codepen.io) simulation, so we can play with.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect new discoveries. I solved the problem by putting the code in the body inside of script tags but that is not my preference. I would rather link a file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the element id. Try this:

```
var caretElement = document.getElementById("caretToggleIh");
```

Comment: Thank you but that did not solve it. The error persists on both buttons.

Comment: It's working for me. You're calling `classList` on `undefined` which gives you that error. Are you sure you applied the change correctly?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect new discoveries. I solved the problem by putting the code in the body inside of script tags but that is not my preference. I would rather link a file.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that syntax in your update. I was using the code inside of script tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway!